# Get input value of dynamically added input

Tags: javascript, input, dynamic

I have several blocks of code. The first block adds the users input to the form, the second block tries to grab that data to evaluate a switch statement. Bc javascript reads all scripts once, my var in block two always returns a value of `null`; the element had no value at the time the .js ran. How do I get the value of an input element created after javascript has read all scripts? Here's a sum of the important parts:

The HTML:

```
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="">Weight Classification:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="weight-class" name="weight">
   </div>
```

The javascript:

```
<script>
  //prior code grabs height and weight and calcs BMI
  switch (BMI >= 16 && BMI < 43) {
    case (BMI >= 16 && BMI < 22):      
      document.getElementById("weight-class").setAttribute("value", "skinny");    
      break;

    case (BMI >= 22 && BMI < 25):
      document.getElementById("weight-class").setAttribute("value", "average");
      break;

    //other cases here...
     default:
     console.log("Error");
  } 
</script>
```

Javascript block 2:

```
<script>
var weight = document.getElementById('weight-class').value; 

  switch (weight) {
    case (skinny):
      console.log("Successful, short");
    break;

    case (average):
      console.log("Successful, average");
    break;

    case (obese):
      console.log("Successful, tall");
    break;

    default:
      console.log("Failed all cases");
    break;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: > The first block adds the users input to the form,

Comment: What that mean ❓ Normally, with a `<form>` in JS, we would `addEventListener` and respond to user interactions such as `'focus'` or `'blur'` and/or `"submit"` to do something with the values...

Comment: The case in block one sets the value of the element

Comment: ‍♂️ Well, regardless, as you say, the scripts will just run b4 there are 'values' to read. So, AFAIK, we would need to use a _callback_ with an `addEventListener`...or you could do a 'weird' _callback_ in a `setTimeout`.

Comment: If you want to do something after an input's value has changed, [listen for that change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).

Comment: addEventListener worked!

Answer (score 2):

You need [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)
since you are changing the value of the input via mutating the `attribute`
thus change event handler wont trigger

```js
var weight = document.getElementById('weight-class');
// Create an observer instance with a callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type == "attributes") {
      let weight = mutation.target.value; // get the value.
      switch (weight) {
        case ('skinny'):
          console.log("Successful, short");
          break;

        case ('average'):
          console.log("Successful, average");
          break;

        case ('obese'):
          console.log("Successful, tall");
          break;

        default:
          console.log("Failed all cases");
          break;
      }
    }
  });
});
// Start observing the target node for attribute mutations

observer.observe(weight, {
  attributes: true //configure it to listen to attribute changes
});
weight.addEventListener('change', function() {
  let weight = this.value;
  console.log('this gets fired when you change the value via input')

})
//lets set the BMI
var BMI = 17 + Math.random() * 7;

switch (BMI >= 16 && BMI < 43) {
  case (BMI >= 16 && BMI < 22):
    document.getElementById("weight-class").setAttribute("value", "skinny");
    break;

  case (BMI >= 22 && BMI < 25):
    document.getElementById("weight-class").setAttribute("value", "average");
    break;

    //other cases here...
  default:
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(BMI);
    
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Weight Classification:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="weight-class" name="weight">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("change", function(){
  var weight = document.getElementById("weight-class").value; 
 
  switch (weight) {
    case "skinny":
      //do something
      break;

    case "average":
      //do something
      break;
    
    case "obese":
      //do something
    break;

    default:
    console.log("Error");
  }  
});
```